# SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified while connecting via asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2012

While connecting to SQL Server 2012 Express from Asp.Net application, I get the following exception:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Though, I can connect remotely to the SQL Server but once I published the application to the server where the db resides, I got the above exception.

I tried various approaches shared on net but nothing worked for me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a problem in your connection string. check the instance name from Sql Server and then paste that instance name in your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

This error is one of the worst, because you normally don't know what exactly the problem is. Here are some possible solutions:

- Check that the server name is correct
- Check that the instance name is correct
- Check that your server is reachable (seems not to be your problem)
- Check that the SQL Browser service is running
- Check the firewall rules

Sometimes SQL Error 26 just hides another problem with the connection (f.e. SQL Error 0).